# Custom redirectUri with Spring Security with OAuth2

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, okta

I am using OAuth2 with Spring Security. The redirectUri in Okta should be mentioned as  `http://localhost:port/login/oauth2/code/okta`. Can I configure a custom Redirect URI and in that case, what other changes I need to do for it to work?

Note:
I added the below configuration for `redirectURI` which is mentioned in the `Registration` static class and had configured the same redirection uri on the Okta side. The application is not able to get the token as it is getting into a recursion. When I changed the `call-back` to `http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/okta`  in the Okta client configuration, it started working?

What is the significance of `redirectURI` parameter in the `application.yml` file.

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          okta:
            client-id: 0oa47p3n9dwLxBkRi5d7
            client-secret: <confidential>
            redirectUri: http://localhost:8080/authorization-code/callback
            scope: openid
            clientName: okta
        provider:
          okta:
            authorizationUri: https://dev-7858070.okta.com/oauth2/default/v1/authorize
            tokenUri: https://dev-7858070.okta.com/oauth2/default/v1/token
            userInfoUri: https://dev-7858070.okta.com/oauth2/default/v1/userinfo
            jwkSetUri: https://dev-7858070.okta.com/oauth2/default/v1/keys
            issuerUri: https://dev-7858070.okta.com/oauth2/default
```

Comment: All you should need to do is in your WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter -> HttpSecurity -> Oauth2Login()..redirectionEndpoint().baseUri(.........) and then configure that redirect uri in Okta.